# GeoServer incorrectly reprojecting layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have my asset data stored in an Oracle 19c spatial database as a table with a geometry column. I've setup a layer in GeoServer in order to overlay my data onto a OpenStreetMap basemap, however, my assets are showing up in Africa instead of in Toronto/Canada.
I've tested overlaying the same data in QGIS and it's showing up correctly in Canada, however, in GeoServer, it is not.

The data is in NAD83 Lambert Conformal Conic projection, however in the GeoServer coordinates reference system, I couldn't find this exact projection so the **native** projection for my layer is blank.

Native SRS: Blank (cannot change it)
Declared SRS: EPSG:3857 (matches OSM)
SRS Handling: Force declared

It might be a problem with the 1041001 projection details in GeoServer. Not sure if it's reading the lat/long swapped and then carrying over to the 3857 projection.

GeoServer version: 2.15.0

OpenLayers library v. 9.0

Open Street basemap: https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms

SRID definition in Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO MDSYS.SDO_CS_SRS (CS_NAME,SRID,AUTH_SRID,AUTH_NAME,WKTEXT,CS_BOUNDS,WKTEXT3D) values ('Conformal Projection NAD83 (Canada)',1041001,1041001,'SPATIALinfo Inc.','PROJCS["Conformal Projection NAD83 (Canada)",
       GEOGCS [ "NAD 83 (Continental US)",
                      DATUM ["NAD 83 (Continental US)", SPHEROID ["GRS 80", 6378137.000000, 298.257222101]],
                                      PRIMEM [ "Greenwich", 0.000000 ],
                                      UNIT ["Decimal Degree", 0.01745329251994330]],
   PROJECTION ["Lambert Conformal Conic"],
    PARAMETER ["Standard_Parallel_1", 77.000000],
            PARAMETER ["Standard_Parallel_2", 49.000000],
            PARAMETER ["Central_Meridian",   -95.000000],
            PARAMETER ["Latitude_Of_Origin",  49.000000],
                 UNIT ["Meter", 1.000000000000]]',null,null);
```

Sample data coordinate value:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 1041001, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1129608.08942139, -561114.717229793, -0.53024043771812564318469287734694537272, -0.84784732010456370891580263849149103528))
```

Here is the HTML/js code I'm using to add OSM basemap and GeoServer layer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0.0/ol.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tiled WMS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0.0/ol.css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 700px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0.0/ol.css">

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>

    <script >
    const layers = [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM(),
  }),
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    //extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': '', 'TILED': true},
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
      transition: 0,
    }),
  }),
];
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: layers,
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-8850000, 5415000],
    zoom: 12,
  }),
});

var currentURL = "http://172.16.1.64:8080";


// poles2 layer
var polesSource2= new ol.source.ImageWMS({
         url:currentURL+"/geoserver/ROGERS_WS/wms",
         params:{
           LAYERS: "ROGERS_WS:MV_GO360_POLE2"
         }
    });
    
var poleslayer2= new ol.layer.Image({
     source: this.polesSource2
})

map.addLayer(poleslayer2);


var scaleLineMetric = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
      units: ['metric'],
      target: document.getElementById("scaleline-metric")
    });
    
map.addControl(scaleLineMetric);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is where the assets are showing on the map:

[image]

I've also tried adding a custom projection in GeoServer matching my source data SRID. The native projection is no longer blank, it is EPSG1041101, however, I faced the same issue. Is there a custom projection that exactly matches the SRS my data is in (1041001)?

```
1041001=PROJCS["NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert", \
  GEOGCS["NAD83", \
    DATUM["North American Datum 1983", \
      SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]], \
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], \
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]], \
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], \
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], \
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], \
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]], \
  PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9802"]], \
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -91.86666666666666], \
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 63.390674999999995], \
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2", 77.0], \
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 6200000.0], \
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 3000000.0], \
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], \
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 48.99999999999999], \
  UNIT["m", 1.0], \
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], \
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH], \
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","3347"]]
```

Comment: If you leave the CRS blank and the data doesn't go where you want it, that's probably an indication you should be using an explicit CRS.

Comment: Thanks. I added more info to the ticket.
I've tried adding a custom projection in Geoserver matching my source data SRID. The native projection is no longer blank, it is EPSG:1041101, however, I faced the same issue. Is there a custom projection that exactly matches the SRS my data is in (1041001)?

Comment: "Ticket"? GIS SE is not a tech support ticketing system for GeoServer. You should probably emphasize what you are asking about, focusing on a way to load a  custom CRS, and less as a bug report.

Comment: Infact GeoServer is projecting your data correctly you just failed to tell it how to project it, so it is taking your origin as null island

Comment: and you almost certainly don't want to force it to be in 3857 - GeoServer will handle the reprojection for you.

Comment: would EPSG:3348 be a possible projection - https://epsg.io/3348